# GPIO4 does not work properly

Tags: gpio

When I try to add pin 4 to the export by "sudo echo 4 >/sys/class/gpio/export" I will get this error message.

```
echo: write error: Device or resource busy
```

It works fine for all other pin numbers though.

Also when attempting the code a kernel module, when I try to change the gpio pin 4 value to 1 (by "gpio_direction_output(4,1);", it will automatically revert back to 0 after a few seconds.

Comment: The other answer did not work for me, but you can run `sudo echo 4 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport` to free the resource and use it.

Answer (score 5):

It is likely you have the 1-wire bus enabled.  The bus is typically used with the DS18B20 temperature sensor.  By default the bus uses GPIO4 when enabled.

If you don't use the 1-wire bus then comment out all the entries starting with w1 in `/boot/config.txt` and reboot.

If you do use the 1-wire bus you can pick another GPIO by modifying the w1 entry. See `/boot/overlays/README` for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. Removing the "dtoverlay=w1-gpio" from the /boot/config.txt helps fixed it.